# Error in the implementation of a voting system

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm writing a program to create a list of voter IDs, and allow them to vote for a candidate. If a voter tries to vote for a candidate that doesn't exist this name should be added to the list. 
When I try copying the name that has been entered on to the candidate_name field using "strcpy" I get a segmentation fault, I tried copying it directly but this overwrites the values of all the previous nodes to the one I enter last. As mentioned in one of the previous solutions for a linked list being overwritten problem I tried strdup as well, but when I do this I don't get the result I'm supposed to. For eg. If I vote for "a" now, and "a" immediately after the function returns "EXISTS", but if I try to vote for "a" first, then "b", then "a" again the function returns "NEW" and for some reason the loop that checks for the existence of a name in the list executes only once even though it has to execute twice. 
I'd be grateful if someone could tell me what I should do to make this right.
Also, why is "strcpy" resulting in a segmentation fault?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct candidate{
    char *candidate_name;
    int vote_count;
    struct candidate *next;
}candidate;
struct candidate *candidate_head=NULL;
typedef struct voter{
    int voterid;
    int has_voted;
    struct voter *next;
}voter;
struct voter *voter_head=NULL;




    char *add_voter(int voterid){
        struct voter *v=voter_head;
        while(v!=NULL){
            if(v->voterid==voterid)
                return "Already exists";
            v=v->next;
        }

        voter *v1=malloc(sizeof(voter));
        v1->voterid=voterid;
        v1->has_voted=0;
        v1->next=voter_head;
        voter_head=v1;
        return "Added";
    }

    char *add_candidate(char *c_name, int voterid){
        int flag=0;
        struct voter *v=voter_head;
        while(v!=NULL){
            if(v->voterid==voterid){
                flag=1;
                if(v->has_voted==1){
                    return "ALREADY VOTED";
                }
                else{
                    v->has_voted=1;
                }
            }    
            v=v->next;
        }

        if(flag==0)
            return "Invalid Voter ID";

            struct candidate *c=candidate_head;
            if(candidate_head!=NULL)
            printf("see-%s\n",candidate_head->candidate_name);
                while(c!=NULL){
                    printf("name0 c%s\n",c->candidate_name);
                    printf("name1 c%s\n",c_name);
                    if(strcmp(c_name,c->candidate_name)==0){
                        c->vote_count++;
                        return "EXISTS";
                    }
                c=c->next;
                }

                struct candidate *c1=malloc(sizeof(candidate));
                // strcpy(c1->candidate_name,c_name);
                c1->candidate_name=strdup(c_name);
                printf("\nname1 %s\n",c1->candidate_name);
                printf("name2 %s\n",c_name);
                c1->vote_count=1;
                c1->next=candidate_head;
                candidate_head=c1;
                candidate_head->next = NULL;
                return "NEW";   


    }


    int main(){

        int voterid,count;
        char *cand=malloc(sizeof(char));
        struct candidate *c=malloc(sizeof(candidate));
        for(count=0;count<4;count++){
            printf("Enter voter ID\n");
            scanf("%d",&voterid);
            printf("%s\n",add_voter(voterid));  
        }

        for(count=0;count<4;count++){
            printf("Enter candidate name\n");
            scanf("%s",cand);
            printf("Enter voter ID\n");
            scanf("%d",&voterid);
            printf("%s\n", add_candidate(cand,voterid));

        }

        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: `char *cand=malloc(sizeof(char));` : you alloced only one byte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After addressing errors in your code that have to do with allocating memory, it seemed to run without error.

***First***, the line:

char *cand=malloc(sizeof(char));   //(second line in main)

only allocates 1 byte to the intended character array cand, so in the next line, `scanf()` returns
**Attempt to write beyond string**.  Allocate more memory for your candidates name.  And free() `cand` when you are 
done with it.
***providing more memory:***

char *cand = malloc(100); // will hold a 99 character name (plus \0)

***Second***, c1->candidate_name has never been given space.  You are attempting to copy into memory that you do not own.
***Note:***  the line:

```
struct candidate *c1=malloc(sizeof(candidate));
```

***does not*** allocate memory for the member candidate_name, you have to do that explicitly

```
c1->candidate_name = malloc(SOME_NUMBER_OF_BYTES);
// then when you are done, free it:  
free(c1->candidate_name);
```